# WSMAN error using Register-PSSessionConfiguration

Tags: powershell, powershell-v5.0

Windows Server 2016 v1607 Build 14393.3930
PowerShell 5.1.14393.3866
This is a Google Cloud VM

I am teaching students some basic PS Remoting. Set up a simple DNSOps group and use ps-remoting to show how the non-admin user can do some admin tasks.

One student ran into an issue registering her ps-session .pssc file - I have never seen this particular error:

```
new-item : The WS-Management service cannot process the request. The service cannot find the resource identified by the resource URI and selectors.
At line:72 char:9
+         new-item -path WSMan:\localhost\Plugin -file "$filepath" -nam ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Item], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

I've ran `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` and `sfc /scannow` with both coming back clean.
I've googled quite a bit, but can't seem to find much about this error.

I've rebooted a number of times as well.

Comment: This needs the command that generates the error.

Comment: Register-PSSessionConfiguration .\DNSOps.pssc
I used the same .pssc and psrc on a different system and it worked so there is some sort of wsman voodoo that I'm not getting